# Application icon is displayed magnified

Tags: java, android, notifications, icons

Since I have updated my application icons, sometimes the icon is displayed magnified when shown as a notification in the header bar of the phone.

With magnified I mean that the center of the icon takes the full size of the notification icon and rest of it is cropped. When I open the list of notification the icon is displayed correctly.

Does someone know this error? It does not happen all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that is because you are using the app's default (`ic_launcher`) Icon when showing your Notifications. *Do correct me if I am wrong though.*

To fix it, you can use one of these options:

1. Visit this link: [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) and select Notification Icons. Then provide your image that you want to display as an Icon in your app's Notifications. The Asset Studio will provide you with a set of Icons for the HDPI, MDPI and XHDPI drawbles for API 9, API 11 and for older Android versions.
2. If you have the latest ADT tools installed in Eclipse, select the File menu -> expand New and select Other (or <kbd>CTRL + N</kbd>). Expand the Android category from in the popup and select **Android Icon Set**. Choose Notification Icons and provide a name. Click the **Next** button and provide your Image in the final step.

I personally prefer the the Android Asset Studio. I have been using since it was still in beta and the ADT had not added this feature yet. But, to each his own.

Again, correct me if I am wrong. Before the downvote barrage begins. ;-)

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Not only pinpointing what the problem was, but also telling me about tools I didn't know before.

Comment: @Mahoni: I'm glad I could be of help. :-)